# Natbib shows reference style without square brackets

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm trying to get natbib to display the `\bibliographystyle{aaai-named}` as [this documents shows](http://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/aaai-named.pdf).

But when I try, I do not get that result there are no square brackets around the author name and author year.

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[english, oneside, 12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[square, authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citep{agrawal2014development}

\bibliographystyle{aaai-named}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

References.bib:

```
@article{agrawal2014development,
    title={Development and Comparison of Open Source based Web GIS Frameworks on WAMP and Apache Tomcat Web Servers},
    author={Agrawal, Sonam and Gupta, Rajan Dev},
    journal={Proceedings International Archives of the Photogrammetry, Remote Sensing and Spatial Information Sciences},
    volume={4},
    pages={1--5},
    year={2014}
}
```

**Edit 1:**
Minimal example was written wrong. It is now updated.

Comment: You want the `\bibliographystyle{aaai-named}` but write `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`. `aaai-named` is a bibliographystyle different.

Comment: You are correct, @RomainPicot - that happens when you create minimal examples and still experiments with what could be wrong. It is now updated, but still not succeeding

Comment: Does natbib should be used? I can provide an answer without.

Comment: No, if you can make the same type of citation and the correct form of `\bibliographystyle`, it will be great.

Comment: My bad I've made a mistake and used apalike and not aaai-named :/

Comment: Can you make it look like [the document](http://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/aaai-named.pdf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `natbib` and using `apalike`:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english, oneside, 12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
\cite{agrawal2014development}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```